# Jupyter Notebooks in VSCode on M1 MacBook Pro fails to start server: OSError: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, jupyter, apple-m1

When trying to use Juypter Notebooks in VSCode with the Jupyter Notebooks extension, the kernel server fails to start and gives this output in the Output -> Jupyter section.

```
OSError: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address
error 10:32:19.266: Error starting server in serverPreload:  [Pr [Error]: Jupyter server crashed. Unable to connect. 
Error code from Jupyter: 1
```

How can I fix this?

This comes after opening up a new project, starting a new virtual environment with Python 3.11 (I was using Poetry) and running `poetry add jupyter`.

I had version `v2023.2.1000592019` of the Jupyter Extension from Microsoft installed.

The correct Poetry virtual environment was selected as the Kernel for Jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to this question: [Launching Jupyter Notebook on localhost results in '[Errno 49] Can't assign requested address', however ip=127.0.0.1 works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60271829/launching-jupyter-notebook-on-localhost-results-in-errno-49-cant-assign-requ)

And the answer is the same, though how to do this within VSCode might not be immediately obvious.

The answer is to add command line options to Jupyter Notebook:

Command-Shift-P type Preferences: Open User Settings

Search for Jupyter command line and hit edit in `settings.json`. Add the `-ip` and `127.0.0.1` entry as show here:

```
    "jupyter.jupyterCommandLineArguments": [
        "--ip",
        "127.0.0.1"
    ],
```

This solved my problem across all my workspaces for opening Jupyter Notebooks.